# Is there a built-in more elegant way of filtering-and-mapping a collection by element type?

Tags: scala, types, scala-collections

If I want to narrow, say, an `Iterable[A]` for all elements of a particular type (e.g. `String`) I can do:

```
as filter { _.isInstanceOf[String] }
```

However, it's obviously desirable to *use* this as an `Iterable[String]` which can be done via a `map`:

```
as filter { _.isInstanceOf[String] } map { _.asInstanceOf[String] }
```

Which is pretty ugly. Of course I could use `flatMap` instead:

```
as flatMap[String] { a => 
  if (a.isInstanceOf[String]) 
    Some(a.asInstanceOf[String]) 
  else
    None
}
```

But I'm not sure that this is any more readable! I have written a function, `narrow`, which can be used via `implicit` conversions:

```
as.narrow(classOf[String])
```

But I was wondering if there was a better built-in mechanism which I have overlooked. Particularly as it would be nice to be able to narrow a `List[A]` to a `List[String]`, rather than to an `Iterable[String]` as it will be with my function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Scala syntax sugar for `isInstanceOf` / `asInstanceOf` is pattern matching:

```
as flatMap { case x: String => Some(x); case _ => None }
```

Because that uses `flatMap`, it should usually return the same collection you had to begin with.

On Scala 2.8, there's an experimental function that does that kind of pattern, defined inside the object PartialFunction. So, on Scala 2.8 you can do:

```
as flatMap (PartialFunction.condOpt(_ : Any) { case x: String => x })
```

Which looks bigger mostly because I did not import that function first. But, then again, on Scala 2.8 there's a more direct way to do it:

```
as collect { case x: String => x }
```

Comment: Neat, is there anywhere else you can use pattern matching that isn't well known?

Comment: Pattern matching applies to `case` statements and `var`/`var` assignments. `Case` statements exists in `match` statements and as a partial function syntactic sugar, the latter being what is used in the example.

Comment: It looks like `partialMap` has been replaced by `collect`: http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/5690.html

Comment: @JoshRosen Thanks! The name `partialMap` was short lived indeed. I didn't even remember it was ever called that.

Answer (score 3):

For the record, here's a full implementation of `narrow`.  Unlike the signature given in the question, it uses an implicit `Manifest` to avoid some characters:

```
implicit def itrToNarrowSyntax[A](itr: Iterable[A]) = new {
  def narrow[B](implicit m: Manifest[B]) = {
    itr flatMap { x => 
      if (Manifest.singleType(x) <:< m)
        Some(x)
      else
        None
    }
  }
}

val res = List("daniel", true, 42, "spiewak").narrow[String]  
res == Iterable("daniel", "spiewak")
```

Unfortunately, narrowing to a specific type (e.g. `List[String]`) rather than `Iterable[String]` is a bit harder.  It can be done with the new collections API in Scala 2.8.0 by exploiting higher-kinds, but not in the current framework.

Comment: Daniel - have you tried you example with `narrow[Int]`? It doesn't work - I assume because the type of the thing in the List gets boxed as a `java.lang.Integer`. Is there a workaround?

Comment: You could have some special cases for primitive types.  That's the only workaround I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

You may use in future:

```
for(a :Type <- itr) yield a
```

But it doesn't work now.
For more information, go to the following links:
http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/1089
http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/900

Comment: However, if there is an extractor, then the following is possible: `for(a @ Type() <- itr) yield a`

Answer (score 1):

Shape preserving: I'm a bit rushed right now so I'm leaving the cast in there, but I'm pretty sure it can be eliminated.  This works in trunk:

```
import reflect.Manifest
import collection.Traversable
import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import collection.mutable.ListBuffer

object narrow {
  class Narrower[T, CC[X] <: Traversable[X]](coll: CC[T])(implicit m1: Manifest[CC[T]], bf: CanBuildFrom[CC[T], T, CC[T]]) {
    def narrow[B: Manifest]: CC[B] = {
      val builder = bf(coll)      
      def isB(x: T): Option[T] = if (Manifest.singleType(x) <:< manifest[B]) Some(x) else None

      coll flatMap isB foreach (builder += _)
      builder mapResult (_.asInstanceOf[CC[B]]) result
    }
  }

  implicit def toNarrow[T, CC[X] <: Traversable[X]](coll: CC[T])(implicit m1: Manifest[CC[T]], bf: CanBuildFrom[CC[T], T, CC[T]]) = 
    new Narrower[T,CC](coll)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(Set("abc", 5, 5.5f, "def").narrow[String])
    println(List("abc", 5, 5.5f, "def").narrow[String]) 
  }
}
```

Running it:

```
Set(abc, def)
List(abc, def)
```